# Soccer positions (i.e. Defender, Midfielder, Forward) is there any order

Tags: statistics, data-science, data-analysis

I am unable to understand if is there any order in soccer position or is just random because I have to answer whether it is ordinal data or not

Comment: If by position you mean the player's number - it is not random-random (there is some statistical correlation - e.g., goalkeeper with no. 1) but there is no strict rule - any combination is allowed.

Comment: so its an ordinal or nor ordinal data is like, best, good bad, or 1st rank,2nd Rank, 3rd rank,4th rank

Comment: @Norman no, it's not ordinal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the variable involved here is categorical and in the rules of football there is no certain order that is associated with the given positions.
Like ->
Defender, Mid-Fielder and Forward
Forward, Mid - Fielder and Defender
Hence, Soccer positions is a nominal scale of measurement.